# MS Word & PDF: Svg image color changed when saving to PDF

Tags: pdf, svg, ms-word

I'm using MS Word 2016 and its new SVG image feature.

As I insert the image in MS Word, the image looks fine:

[image]

However, after I save the file to PDF, it turns to this

[image]

I want to know, what is wrong? While some other images do not have this problem. It seems have something to do if I use the `alpha` (transparent) value in these images.

Comment: create a [mcve], submit that to microsoft's bugtracker for MS office.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, I'm not familiar with MS's bug report system. I'll do it right now.